# Multi-select options returning results for both selections in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

First off i'm new to coding so my terms could be terrible, but I got a multiselect box set up in React with each option set to filter out some data. my problem i'm having is selecting any of my filters causes every filter to be applied at the same time.

This is for filtering out some videos, allowing multiple filters to be applied.

```
class FilterItems extends React.Component {
  FilterUnsafeItemBy(item){
    var unsafeLibrary = /(^z$|^cars$|trucks|restricted|various|stuff|special|other|misc|\(some\))/i;
    var unsafeLibrarySpecific = [7066,16517];
    var unsafeServerIds = [2423,3062];
    return (( item ) && this.props.isMovie && (item.library.lib_title.match(unsafeLibrary)
      || unsafeLibrarySpecific.includes(item.library._id)
      || unsafeServerIds.includes(item.server._id)));
  }
  FilterUHDItemBy(item){
    var nonUHDresolutions = ["1080","720","480","sd","576"];
    return (( item ) && this.props.isMovie && (nonUHDresolutions.includes(this.props.item.vid_resolution)))
  }
  render() {
    if (this.props.isMovie){
    return(
    <>
    {
      ((this.props.safeSearch && this.FilterUnsafeItemBy(this.props.item))
        || (this.props.UHDSearch && this.FilterUHDItemBy(this.props.item))
      ) ? (
       <></>
      ) : (
      <VideoItem item={this.props.item} index={this.props.index} size={this.props.size}/>
      )
    }
    </>
   )
  }
   else {
     return (
       <div>{this.props.item._id.vid_grandparent_title}</div>
     )
   }
  }
}
```

I got my select box options as `UHDSearch` and `safesearch`
so my hope was it would set either of these depending on what ones was selected in the select box with the option of selecting both if needed.

What is it i need to do to get my select box to only apply the options that are selected and not apply every option?
IE: these:

```
((this.props.safeSearch && this.FilterUnsafeItemBy(this.props.item))
  || (this.props.UHDSearch && this.FilterUHDItemBy(this.props.item))
```

Comment: And what is your question (hint: a question ends with a question mark)?

Comment: Sorry was a bit overwelmed by the way the site makes you post questions having multple different text box's. but i added my question onto the end.